# LTSP clients stopped recognizing USB keys

Tags: ltsp

We are experiencing some problem's with are LTSP server regarding USB Drive on the 
users thinclient. It use to work flawlessly and I guess an update is to blame for 
it not working anymore.

It doesn't mount the usbdrive and I can't see any system entry when I have a look 
at lsusb or dmesg.

Any idea's ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this would help but I've found that I've had to add a few extra modules for some USB drives/phones to be connected.

Add the following to your /var/lib/tftpboot/ltsp/i386/lts.conf file.

```
# Required so clients can mount HTC Desire phones as disk drives
MODULE_01 = "usb-uhci"
MODULE_02 = "usb-storage"
MODULE_03 = "sd_mod"
```